# swagger POST node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger

I make my GET services work in Swagger (with Node.js), but I am not able to make the POST work. Can someone point out where I am making mistake in below testPost service?

my service definition

```
 "/people/testPost": {
  "post": {
    "summary": "write the test POST.",
    "description": "Test",
    "operationId": "myService",
    "consumes": [
        "application/json"
      ],
    "tags": [
      "test"
    ],
    "parameters": [
    {
        "name":"body",
        "paramType":"body",
        "description": "body for the POST request",
        "required":false
      }

    ]
```

In service (filename = myService.js),  I am trying this

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.post("/people/testPost", function (req, res) {
console.log("I am in the testPost service);  //this gets printed
console.log("The req body", req.body)   //says 'undefined'
});
```

Here is my CURL command I use to POST

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"arg1":"open", "arg2":"IVR","arg3":"", "arg4" :"1234567"}' http://localhost:8016/people/testPost
```

Any simple POST request that uses Swagger with Node (all I need is how to configure my "body" in the json file) would, hopefully, gets me going

Some one, please, look into my "parameters" and the curl POST and see where I need to make changes/corrections.

Comment: is this service definition is part of big file or You've forgot to close curly brace for attribute "post" and "/people/testPost" ?

Comment: It seems nothing in request body ?

Comment: num8er, thanks for looking into it. Yes, it is part of a big file. I just want to know how the POST works with Swagger. any simple example (a link to a working hello world program) is good enough.

Comment: Indra Uprade, do you want to know the curl command that I use to POST? clarify a bit more as to what you want to see in there?

Answer (score 0):

because you're receiving JSON request you need an appropriate handler for this. For JSON you should use `app.use(bodyParser.json());`, see example on [module page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#expressconnect-top-level-generic).

`app.use(bodyParser)` don't needed btw.

Comment: That was my copying error :) yes, I am using app.use(bodyParser.json()). I corrected the original post, but the problem still stays.

Comment: Oh, ok. Seem like it's a problem with Swagger configuration, take a look on one of the official [examples](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/test/specs/v2/petstore.json#L62-L72), in your API missing `in` and `schema` properties.

Comment: "parameters": [
        {
            "in":"body",
            "name":"Pet",
            "description": "body for the POST request",
            "required":false,
           "schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Pet"}
          }
          
        ],   and I defined my  'Pet' in definitions:{ Pet:{name:"myPet"}} .. still the same issue. what am I missing?

Comment: Are you validating your configuration? If no, I think you should [try it out](http://editor.swagger.io/#/). It's very useful especially on beggining.

Comment: Yes I am validating my config file using http://bigstickcarpet.com/swagger-parser/www/index.html  . I just need a simple example that takes POST params and transfers them to a service. So if I get my "parameters" right, I should be good to go. Any other suggestion, please feel free to post them here

Comment: Try to log whole request and inspect it, data could be hidden in `swagger` property for example.

Comment: I am using CURL to post the data -- curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"arg1":"open", "arg2":"IVR","arg3":"", "arg4" :"1234567"}' http://localhost:8016/people/testPost   ..I just have to carry my arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4 to my service in body. Can you help me with the config json file on how to set these args in there?

Comment: You need to define all parameters in body's schema

Comment: Thanks. I did this now: [
{
    "in":"body",
    "name":"body",
    "description": "body for the POST request",
    "required":false,
    "schema": {"$ref":"#/definitions/inBody"}
  }
] 
}
}          "definitions": {
     "inBody": {

  "properties": {
    "RequestSystem": {
      "type": "string"
    }}}}   .. it did not work but do you still see any issues here?